# dismiss keyboard on tapping on any UIControl objects

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I have multiple keyboard provoking elements...`UITextField`, `UITextView` and `UISearchBar`.

I would like to dismiss `UIKeyboard` upon touch anywhere except keyboard and currently active "text editing" element.

I've implemented

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    name.resignFirstResponder() //UITextField
    notes.resignFirstResponder() //UITextView
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This works if user taps on an "inert" element...background or userDisabledView... but most of my View is made up of "active" elements like `UITableView` and `UIButtons`...

Is there a way to make this possible, regardless where the tap is made.

---

The only way I know of is to use a large invisible button that slides over the view whenever `UIKeyboard` is presented, which calls `self.view.endEditing(true)`, then retracts to offscreen.

Any help?

### NOTE: I resolved if tap is on UITableView, by implementing `self.view.endEditing(true)` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, would still like to hear of other methods for the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can attach tap gesture for every controls inside the view,* `tapGestRecog.cancelsTouchesInView=NO` *prevents the tap recognizer to be the only one to catch all the taps then resign your keyboard on tapAction.*

First in your viewDidLoad, add keyboard notification:-

```
// Listen for keyboard appearances and disappearances
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Now set a BOOL value , to set a value whether keyboard is present or not

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
     isKeyboardPresent=TRUE;
    // Do something here
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
     isKeyboardPresent=False;
    // Do something here
}
```

Now, add tap gesture to all your controls

```
for(UIView *vw in [self.view subviews])
     {
         UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestRecog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(controlTapAction)];
         tapGestRecog.delegate=self;
         [tapGestRecog setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
         tapGestRecog.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
         [vw addGestureRecognizer:tapGestRecog];

     }
-(IBAction) controlTapAction
{
  if(isKeyboardPresent)
   {
       [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
  } 
}
```

Comment: so the `cancelsTouchesInView` makes it so that the "touch" registers for the tapGesture and as if tapGesture wasn't there??

Comment: okay, but that also means every touch on the these views would call `self.view.endEditing(true)`...could this cause problems? or is it a very low-demand call?

Comment: @Dustin No, you have to check whether keyboard is present or not, then call endEditing if present. Check my updated answer.

Comment: As, somebody has down-voted the answer that is nice as user has rights to downvote any answer he /she wants to, but it will be nice if you add some clarification what is wrong in this ;)

Comment: every answer has been down voted? seems like someone has done this out of bitterness

Comment: Will did it worked for you, as It is working in my case. @Dustin

Comment: I haven't had a chance to implement it yet. just reading it, it seems logical that it should work..although I only know `Swift` so the `isKeyboardPresent=TRUE;` part is a little confusing...Am I creating something here? or setting something's value to true?

Comment: You have to make a global BOOL variable "isKeyboardPresent" in your view controller , so that you can check the wether keyboard is presnt in your screen or not @Dustin  .. did u got it?

Comment: That is not possible @Dustin , I hope you got the logic from the code written in Objective C, rest you have to convert it in swift.Moreover you must know Stack overflow doesn't encourage this kind of request.

Comment: ok, so I'll have to ask another question to find out why the tapGesture is crashing the app with error "tapGestRecog:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9702c3ba00" in order to know if you answer is good or not

Comment: @Dustin Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78500/discussion-between-vizllx-and-dustin).

Answer (score 1):

This Always worked for me.....!!

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) 
{

```
    self.view.endEditing(true )
```

}

Comment: when touching say a `userEnabled(true) UIButton`? Because I don't get `touchesBegan` func when touching "active" elements.

Comment: what..??? i didnt get u...!! And i gave what worked for me any ways thanks for the downvote..!!

Comment: i didn't down vote you as my rep is under 125, but you probably got down voted because your suggested answer uses a method that I already stated that I am using~!

Answer (score 1):

```
//currently active "text editing" element.
var firstResponderView : UIView?

var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer?

//cover the currently active "text editing" element.
var smallView:UIView?

//dont't cover the keyboard
var bigView: UIView?

func createView(){
    bigView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    bigView!.userInteractionEnabled=false

    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "endEditing")

    smallView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    smallView!.userInteractionEnabled=false
    bigView!.addSubview(smallView!)
    self.view.addSubview(bigView!)
    self.update()
}

func endEditing(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.update()
}

//call this after any view become first responder or resign
func update() {

    if(firstResponderView?.isFirstResponder()==true)
    {
        bigView!.addGestureRecognizer(tap!)
        bigView!.userInteractionEnabled = true
        smallView!.frame = firstResponderView!.frame
    }
    else{
        bigView!.removeGestureRecognizer(tap!)
        bigView!.userInteractionEnabled = false
        smallView!.frame=CGRectZero
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vizllx have you test you answer at UITextView,it coun't work for me at my  test code

Answer (score 1):

you want to dismiss keybord on active controls when they tapped, for that you have to use

```
resignFristResponder()
```

on every active controls
like if you have a UIButton than you have to put this method on buttonClick Action. like ex-

```
  @IBAction func nextButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
{

    txtlang.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

its only example.
Hope it helps you

edit 1 = you can also use `endEditing()` method as it is.
**my english is very poor. sorry for that.