# How to ignore all UIControl Taps, when using the tap to close UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikeyboard

This issue is stemming from my previous question [dismiss keyboard on tapping on any UIControl object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388641/dismiss-keyboard-on-tapping-on-any-uicontrol-objects).

So when user has a keyboard present, I want the user to be able to tap anywhere outside of keyboard or UITextView to close keyboard. This works...But I also want that "first" tap that closes the keyboard to not cause any other actions.

i.e. `UIKeyboard` is present...user taps anywhere to close and happens to tap on a `UIButton`. `UIKeyboard` is closed and `UIButton`'s action is NOT sent.

---

I tried to place

```
@IBAction func blahblah(sender: UIButton){
    if keyboardShow == false {//UIButtons action here
    }
}
```

But with some `println()` tests, it's showing that the keyboard is closed(thus `keyboardShow` is set to false) before `UIButton` registers the tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I also want that "first" tap that closes the keyboard to not cause any other actions.

You can do it the way you are doing it, but that's very inflexible because you have to deal with all those other controls separately and individually.

The simplest way to do this is simply to put an invisible view on top of your entire "screen" (i.e., add it to your view controller's view, in front of all views) — except that it should be behind the text view.

```
text view
secret invisible view
all other views (buttons etc.)
```

Normally, your secret invisible view's `userInteractionEnabled` is `false`, so taps just fall through to whatever is behind it, as if the invisible view were not even there. The user can tap buttons and so on.

But when you show the keyboard, you also set your secret invisible view's `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` and give it a tap gesture recognizer. Thus, when the user taps outside the text view, the tap gesture recognizer responds, and you dismiss the keyboard.

When you dismiss the keyboard, you reverse all of that: remove the tap gesture recognizer and turn the invisible view's `userInteractionEnabled` to `false`.

I use this kind of trick all the time in my apps.

It is also possible to be more sophisticated: put your interfering invisible view in front of *everything* and override its touch handling (`hitTest:`). Here's an example of a view that blocks all touches except touches that would land on one particular `passthruView` located *behind it*:

```
class BlockerView: UIView {
    weak var passthruView : UIView!
    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if let pv = self.passthruView {
            let pt = pv.convertPoint(point, fromView: self)
            if pv.pointInside(pt, withEvent: event) {
                return nil // let the touch fall thru
            }
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I thought to do that but I have multiple TextEditing Controls and it would be tedious to bring the invisible button above everything except current TextEditing Control.

Comment: No it wouldn't. It's easy to rearrange the layering order of views. What _you_ are doing is tedious.

Comment: okay i may have to do it because, what i just did worked for the UIButton but not for the UITableView, could you give an example. say I have 5 UITextViews. how do I bring invisible button above the other four but below the current?

Comment: Bring the invisible view to the front and then bring the current text view to the front.

Comment: And it is possible to be even more sophisticated about this: instead of moving things to the front, you put the invisible view in front and override `hitTest`. That, after all, is how a popover works (with its `passthroughViews`).

Comment: Well, of course I'm not to blame if you implement what I said incorrectly. What I said does work.

Comment: I can't get the UITextView or UITextField to go in front of invisible button? The UITextView and UITextField are in a subView of View...UISearchBar is directly in View and it's working great now. i guess I need to rethink my layout. ty this should work with some rearranging

Comment: Maybe they are inside something else?